# Clicking reverts array order in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a Trivia App in React. I shuffle the answers before rendering them as buttons and want to change the color of the buttons if the answer is right/wrong:

```
export default function QuestionCard({ question }){
    const [isAnswered, setIsAnswered] = useState(false)
    
    const initAnswers = [...question.incorrect_answers, question.correct_answer]
    
    function shuffleAnswers(answers){
        var j, x, i; 
        for(i = answers.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
            j = Math.floor(Math.random()* (i + 1));
            x = answers[i];
            answers[i] = answers[j];
            answers[j] = x;
        }
        return answers
    }

    const answers = shuffleAnswers(initAnswers);

    const handleAnswerClick = (answer) => {
        setIsAnswered(true)
    }

    return(
        <Card>
            {question.question}
            <div>
                {answers.map(answer => (
                    <Button 
                        key={answer}
                        onClick={() => handleAnswerClick(answer)}
                        color={isAnswered && answer === question.correct_answer ?
                             'primary' : 
                             isAnswered && answer !== question.correct_answer ? 'secondary' : 
                            'default'}
                    >
                        {answer}
                    </Button>
                ))}
            </div>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

When after clicking the Button, the Card 'forgets' the order from `shuffleAnswers()` and returns the Buttons in their original order. Any

Comment: Create a reproducible issue in the sandbox?

Comment: I think the issue is the shuffleAnswers function is being called every time the button rendered in the answers.map() method is called....I just don't know how else to set the answers without invoking the shuffleAnswers function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

On each render cycle `initAnswers` and `answers` are both redeclared/redefined, thus when state is updated when a card is clicked on and state updates the component rerenders with new `initAnswers` and shuffled  `answers` arrays.

## Solution

You want to only initialize and shuffle the answers once per set of question answers. You *could* use an `useEffect` hook to shuffle and store in state the `answers` array, but IMO just memoizing the `answers` array is better.

1. Use `useMemo` hook with answers dependencies (i.e. only recompute when the incorrect and correct answers for `question` prop update.
2. Move the `shuffleAnswers` utility function *out of* the component, it doesn't have any state/prop/component dependencies and we don't want to redefine it each render cycle either.
3. Move `initAnswers` *into* the hook callback so it isn't an external dependency to computing `answers` (*otherwise you would need to memoize it as well!*).

Code:

```
function shuffleAnswers(answers) {
  let j, x, i;
  for (i = answers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    x = answers[i];
    answers[i] = answers[j];
    answers[j] = x;
  }
  return answers;
}

function QuestionCard({ question }) {
  const [isAnswered, setIsAnswered] = useState(false);

  const answers = useMemo(() => {
    const initAnswers = [
      ...question.incorrect_answers,
      question.correct_answer
    ];

    return shuffleAnswers(initAnswers);
  }, [question.incorrect_answers, question.correct_answer]);

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

[image: Edit clicking-reverts-array-order-in-react]

## Fun Fact

You can use array destructuring assignment to swap two values in an array in a single line without a third variable

```
[answers[j], answers[i]] = [answers[i], answers[j]]
```

So your utility can reduce to

```
function shuffleAnswers(answers) {
  let i, j;
  for (i = answers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [answers[j], answers[i]] = [answers[i], answers[j]];
  }
  return answers;
}
```